# Still can't center font awesome icons for some reason

Tags: html

[image]Here is my HTML:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td class="icon"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/maxmatkovski/"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></td>
            <td class="icon"><a href="https://github.com/maxmatkovski">  <i class="fab fa-github" ></i></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

I've tried using classes within CSS to help center it; however it was not centering horizontally, as in the two icons side by side.

Here is my CSS:

```
[class^="fab"].fab {
    color:white;
    font-size: 80px;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
}

.icon{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: could you add an image on how it looks?

Answer (score 0):

After including the `<script>` for [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/), your icons weren't visible on the page as you gave them a `color` of white. Once I changed the color to something other than white, the icons were visible.

Using [CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) you can put the icons in a row and utilize `align-items: center` to center them vertically along the main axis and `justify-content: center` to horizontally center the row items along the cross-axis. If you give the table a `width` of 100%, the icons will be centered in the page.

```css
table {
  background: #2EA0C1;
  width: 100%;
}

table tr {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 1rem;
}

[class^="fab"].fab {
    color:white;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin: 0 .5rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td class="icon"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/maxmatkovski/"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></td>
              <td class="icon"><a href="https://github.com/maxmatkovski">  <i class="fab fa-github" ></i></td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- Include Font Awesome Script -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e03d7ac5cf.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: This still is centered to the left or am I missing something?

Comment: @maxthemarble Since you didn't include a picture of what you actually want. I wasn't sure if you wanted the icons centered in the page or in the `<tr>` that they are nested in. Can you include a picture of what you want it to look like? My answer aligns them horizontally and vertically.

Comment: @maxthemarble If you wanted the icons to be centered in the page, you just needed to give the parent container `<table>` an explicit width so the flex container could horizontally center evenly in the space. In the first example, the width of table was only fitting to it's content so the icons were horizontally and vertically centered but on the left part of the viewport due to the table width. Have a look at my updated answer above.

Comment: I added an image. I would like it to be centered horizontally only within the block element.

Comment: @maxthemarble I saw the image you included and updated my answer. It's still not clear from your explanation what exactly it is you want. Do you want the two icons to be centered horizontally in the blue container you included in the picture? If so, that's what the above code in my answer accomplishes. If not, please try to explain what your after more clearly.

Comment: @maxthemarble Feel free to mark my answer as accepted or let me know what it is your still looking to accomplish. Otherwise, I will remove my answer to tidy things up here.